# awk one liner that prints the whole line if certain field containts specific number

Tags: awk, match

I have a huge log file test.log it contains 50 fields

I would like to use awk to match a number '0' in field 20 and only if it matches 0 then print the whole line

to further enhance this I would like to match 2 or more fields and if they match then print the whole line.

Please help:)
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '$20 == 0' your-file.txt

awk '$20 == 0 && $21 == 1' your-file.txt
```

Where $20 means field 20 and $21 means field 21.

Comment: Thanks foundart, to take if a bit further, what if I wanted to print the whole line if field 20 was other than '0' ?

Comment: @user2301195 you REALLY can't figure out the syntax for `not equal to` given the syntax for `equal to` is `==`?